# Remove all colors but one

Tags: color, inkscape, images, image-editing

In Inkscape is there any way to remove from a photo all color, except one, and to instead either use shades of that color or that color and shades of black??

Though I'm not entirely sure, I think this has also been referred to as desaturing an image?

My intention is to make a handful of images better meld with the color palette of the website by doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Inkscape is a vector graphics application, while your requirement seems related to rasterized images. GIMP, Photoshop, etc. are better suited for this.

Comment: The effect you are after is called "sepia". Google for "gimp sepia tutorial" or similar and you will probably find what you are after.

Comment: Create a rectangle the same dimension as your image,  use the dropper tool to select the colour from the image. Use Filter -> Colour -> Greyscale to remove all other colours then place the rectangle you previously coloured on top (use Object -> Raise to Top if it is lower in the z order) - and mess with the opacity slider in accessible through FIll and Stroke, or move it to a separate layer(Layer-> Add Layer -> Position Above current layer, then, Layer-> Move Selection to Layer Above) for more Gimp/Photoshop like ways to blend the rectangle's colour  with the image